# Copy/Paste on TreeView with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to implement copy&paste on WPF TreeView with Caliburn.Micro but I stuck at the beginning. Problem is that I don't know to get current item on TreeView was copied or pasted when event is invoked. Below is xaml for TreeView and event handler. Any suggestion?

```
    <TreeView Name="Nodes" AllowDrop="True">
        <TreeView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
                <MenuItem Header="Copy" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Copy($source, $eventArgs)]"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Cut" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Cut]"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Paste" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Paste($this)]" IsEnabled="{Binding IsPasteEnabled}"></MenuItem>
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuCommand}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:TreeListViewModel+Node}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>

public void Copy(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    // to do...
}
```

Edited:
Source: http://dfiles.eu/files/bsm545ti3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be useful, but I did something similar using the `cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext` property to resolve the `DataContext` to a particular `ViewModel`. In my case I had several different types of `ViewModel` all inheriting from a base `TreeViewItemViewModel` class, but that shouldn't really be something you need to consider here.

Essentially, I was setting the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu` to the actual `ViewModel` represented by the current `TreeView` node, allowing me to call an action I had defined on the `ViewModel`.

In your case, you probably don't want a generic Copy/Paste defined on the `ViewModel`, but you may be able to fire `Copy`/`Cut`/`Paste` events (using the `Caliburn.Micro` `EventAggregator`), from each of the `ViewModels`, passing themselves in the event information.

The important bit:

```
<ContextMenu cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

I'd defined different a `ContextMenu` depending on what the node represented, so it lived in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. It looked something like this (I was using a `StackPanel` to display multiple objects, allowing a `ContextMenu` to appear if the `StackPanel` itself was clicked.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}"
                          DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:TreeListViewModel+Node}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <MenuItem Header="Cut" cal:Message.Attach="Cut" />
                <MenuItem Header="Copy" cal:Message.Attach="Copy" />
                <MenuItem Header="Paste" cal:Message.Attach="Paste" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

There may be a much simpler/straightforward approach.

Also worth searching the `Caliburn.Micro` discussions, e.g: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/256163

Comment: Hi, I think your solution helped me : ) but I have also uploaded my project so if you could review it and maybe tell me how to set "Paste" button enabled depending if some Node was copied/cut.

Comment: Hi, I'll try and give it a look when I get home. I would probably try keep track of the Copied/Cut item in a `NodeClipBoard` property on the `ViewModel` that hosts this `TreeView` control, then you could fill the property when `Copy/Cutting` and use it when `Pasting`. You could tie the `Paste` command to a `CanPaste` property (CM convention which will enable/disable the option), which checks if the `NodeClipBoard` item was non-null. You may have to make an additional flag to manage `Cut` (so the `ClipBoard` is cleared after a paste. There may be cleaner approaches =D

Comment: I have modified my project, but I have kind a "bug". When I copy some child node and press paste on the other. This node have available paste command which it shouldn't because Clipboard is cleared each time.

Comment: It sounds like you may have to call something like `NotifyPropertyChanged(() => CanPaste)` to let the UI know the `CanPaste` property may have refreshed after you've pasted. It may also be worth investigating how you're implementing the copy/paste (deciding if you want to actually create a clone of the `ViewModel` at an existing node, or moving the existing instance around (for Cuts).

Comment: This is how I have resolved it. Each time user right click the node it becomes selected and also I call for `node.NotifyOfPropertyChange("CanPaste");`